# I am using angular material, how to send my input field Email to my sendmail method

Tags: angular, angular-material

This my HTML code where my input field contains email

```html
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter Email ID" [(ngModel)]="sendemail" >
    
    <mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
      <button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="sendemail" color="primary" (click)="sendmail()">Send</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
```

This is my method for sending email in component.ts

```js
      sendemail: string;
    
      ngOnInit() {}
    
      sendmail(){
    
        this.api.sendFileMail(this.email).subscribe(data=>{
          console.log(data, "email id done")
        })
        this.toaster.successToastr('File sent successfully');
    
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the wrong property. In template you are using `sendemail` model. And the controller you are using `this.email` property. Just change your `sendemail` method as below.

```
sendmail(){
    this.api.sendFileMail(this.sendemail).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data, "email id done")
    })
    this.toaster.successToastr('File sent successfully');

  }
```

Comment: thanks it worked

Comment: @HarishReddy can you give an upvote and show some support

Answer (score 0):

Aren't u using the wrong property? You're binding the `sendemail` property but sending the `this.email`.

And since you're using buttons you can always do something like this:

```
<input #mail matInput placeholder="Enter Email ID">

<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
  <button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="sendemail" color="primary" (click)="sendmail(mail.value)">Send</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

```
  sendmail(email){
    this.api.sendFileMail(email)
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data, "email id done"));
    
    this.toaster.successToastr('File sent successfully');
  }
```